# How to replace all numeric characters with a specific value?

Tags: java, io

I want to replace all numbers inside a string with specific values.

Teststring: `-SD12431;ABC333`

How can I identify blocks of digits, and especially replace them with a (dynamic) new value?

For example after replacement:
`-SDfirst;ABCsecond`?

Comment: Have your tried regular expressions?

Comment: Yes I can of course match digits with `\\d+` but how would I split the string based on this?

Comment: You can use Pattern.split or a Matcher to iterate through the matched sequences.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Does your string always look like `-StringNumber;StringNumber`? How this mapping should work? Do you have some predefined `first` `second` values somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(str);
    int n = 0;
    while(m.find()) {
        if (++n == 1) {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, "first");
        } else {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, "second");
        }
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    s = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Both works, either `StringBuffer` or `test = test.replaceFirst(token, "first");`. Would you consider SB to be favored over looping replaceFirst?

Comment: 1 reason is performance (if it matters); 2 - it may be more flexible (if needed); otherwise I would use replaceFirst because it's one line solution

Answer (score 5):

The [`replaceFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method will let you do this if you use it in a loop.

```
String myNewString = myString.replaceFirst("\\d+","first");
```

If you loop over the this statement, each invocation of `replaceFirst()` will replace the first group of digits with whatever you provide as a second argument.

Comment: you need to write \\d and not \d :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
yourString = yourString.replaceFirst("\\d+",firstString).replaceFirst("\\d+",secondString);  //and so on
```

or use a loop if it fits your needs better

Answer (score -1):

You can use the replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement) function of the string class.

Look at
http://javarevisited.blogspot.fr/2011/12/java-string-replace-example-tutorial.html

So in first argument you have to use a regex for finding digit such as :

- "[0-9]" will find a single digit
- "[0-9]+" will find one or more digit

  ```
  String testString = "-SD12431;ABC333";
  ArrayList<String> remplaceBy= new ArrayList<String>();
  remplaceBy.add("first");
  remplaceBy.add("second");
  remplaceBy.add("third");

  String newString = testString;
  String oldString ="";
  int i =0;
  while(!newString.equals(oldString))
  {
  oldString = new String(newString);
  newString = newString.replaceFirst("[0-9]+",remplaceBy.get(i));
  i++;
  System.out.println("N1:"+newString);
  System.out.println("O1:"+oldString); 
  }
  System.out.println("New String"+newString);
  ```

Comment: If you use `replaceAll()`, you cannot replace different parts of the original string with different replacements, as the question asks. And your example uses `replaceFirst()`